# Why do I get [nan] when using TensorFlow to calculate a simple linear regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

When I use TensorFlow to calculate a simple linear regression I get [nan], including: w, b and loss.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

liner = w*x+b

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(liner-y))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()

x_data = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000]
y_data = [265000, 324000, 340000, 412000, 436000, 490000, 574000, 585000, 680000]                                                    

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_data, y: y_data})

nw, nb, nloss = sess.run([w, b, loss], {x: x_data, y: y_data})

print(nw, nb, nloss)
```

Output:

```
[ nan] [ nan] nan

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing by using such a high learning rate (1 in your case). Try with a learning rate of 0.001. Also your data needs to be divided by 1000 and the number of iterations increased and it should work. This is the code I tested and works perfectly.

```
x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y_data = [265, 324, 340, 412, 436, 490, 574, 585, 680]

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'ro', label='Original data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], 0, 1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = W * x_data + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for step in range(0,50000):
   sess.run(train)
   print(step, sess.run(loss))
print (step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'ro')
plt.plot(x_data, sess.run(W) * x_data + sess.run(b))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I divide my data by 1000, it can work.But why it doesn't work before?

Comment: eh that's mostly because that 1000 doesn't provide any information and was making the float overflow with your large learning rate. It shows even in this toy example how it's good to normalize your values.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the explanation I believe:

```
for i in range(10):
     print(sess.run([train, w, b, loss], {x: x_data, y: y_data}))
```

Gives the following result:

```
[None, array([  4.70380012e+10], dtype=float32), array([ 8212000.], dtype=float32), 2.0248419e+12] 
[None, array([ -2.68116614e+19], dtype=float32), array([ -4.23342041e+15], dtype=float32),
6.3058345e+29] 
[None, array([  1.52826476e+28], dtype=float32), array([  2.41304958e+24], dtype=float32), inf] [None, array([
-8.71110858e+36], dtype=float32), array([ -1.37543819e+33], dtype=float32), inf] 
[None, array([ inf], dtype=float32), array([ inf], dtype=float32), inf]
```

Your learning rate is simply too big, so you "overcorrect" the value of `w` at each iteration (see as it oscillates between negative and positive, with increasing absolute value). You get higher and higher values, until something reaches infinity, which creates Nan values. Just lower (a lot) the learning rate.

Comment: 0.000000001 works for me, although the bias converges too slowly. It's consistent with @user3217278's answer: he dividied the inputs by 10³, which will divide the typical MSE by 10⁶; so if we don't do that, we should divide his LR by 10⁶.